# Why is there more than one constructor in this Java code?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I was given a reference sheet to print while listening to a lecture in my Java class (Java I). This is not homework, it's just something to look over to get an understanding of objects, classes, and constructors. My question is, are the multiple constructors necessary? The first one just declares all the variables, and the second initializes them. Can't this be done in one constructor? Here is the code for the constructors. You're more than welcome to code up an example or just help me understand what I'm looking at. I'm very new to constructors.

```
public class Puppy 
{ 
    private String name;      // puppy's name
    private String breed;     // breed of dog
    private int age;          // chronological age of dog
    private String vet;       // name of vet

    public Puppy() 
    {
        name = " ";
        breed = " ";
        age = 0;
        vet = " ";
    } // end of Puppy constructor

    // method initializing data fields to specific values
    public Puppy(String n, String b, int a, String v) 
    {
        name = n;
        breed = b;
        age = a;
        vet = v;
    } // end of Puppy constructor
```

Comment: The default value of a reference type (like string) is "null". This is different from an empty string. The first constructor makes sure that things like name and breed have an empty string value instead of a null value. *if* this is necessary, it's typically done inline when the fields are defined though.

Comment: well first one will initialize object with hard coded values used inside constructor, and using second constructor you can pass in your own values and object with that values will be created.

Comment: Seems that the first constructor is not needed - because the variables can be initialized to default values on declaration. That said, there are some frameworks and tools that requires that you'll explicitly declare an empty constructor. If such tool/framework is used - it could explain it.

Comment: Additionaly, the code for the first constructor could also be `this(" ", " ", 0, " ");`. In that way you could think of the second constructor as the 'basis'. If no values are provided by the user you just make a 'default' Puppy object.

Comment: Naming of the constructor parameters could certainly be more clear. Using parameter names like `name` and then assign the field like `this.name = name` improves understandability.

Answer (score 4):

The two constructors are to provide the user of this class two ways to create an object:

- with the first Constructor's arguments
- with the second Contructor's arguments

Essentially, if the user provides no values, the first constructor kicks into effect and gives the instance variables default values.

Answer (score 1):

None of the constructors *declare* fields ("variables") of the object. They're declared here:

```
private String name;      // puppy's name
private String breed;     // breed of dog
private int age;          // chronological age of dog
private String vet;       // name of vet
```

The first constructor just creates some kind of an "empty" Puppy object, while the second provides an ability to create some specific Puppy.

Also, it's possible to assign (initialize) values in the declaration part, so you won't need `Puppy()` anymore:

```
private String name = " ";
private String breed = " ";
private int age = 0;
private String vet = " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

[About Overloading Methods](http://java.about.com/od/o/g/overloading.htm)

One of the most popular examples of overloaded methods is **System.out.println()**, which allows you to place arguments like String, primitive types, or even expressions.

You do this because *you want a method to handle different types of arguments* and do something about that without just crashing.

In this case you are overloading the *constructor*, so the arguments you pass when you make an instance to that class (previously defined in your class file) will be valid.

May i add a constructor is a shorcut of passing values to an object without calling a method *after* creating the object.

```
Person alicia = new Person("Alicia Roberts"); //the variable holding the full name is set.

Person alicia = new Person(); //create the object
alicia.setFullName("Alicia Roberts"); // pass a value by a method
```

Answer (score 1):

No, (in general) having more than 1 constructor is not **necessary**.
The reason to have more than 1 is for the **convenience** of whoever might use your code.

Often a reason for supplying multiple constructors is that different or different amounts of information might be known at the time the constructor is called.
So supplying a constructor like

> Puppy(String n, String b, int a, String v)

is more convenient than making your user do:

```
Puppy p = new Puppy();
p.setName("Rover");
p.setAge(12);
p.setBreed("Mutt");
p.setVet("Dr. Dolittle");
```